# Efficient array scalar products in VBA

Tags: vba

Generating two arrays, filled for example purposes with a column of ones. We know that scalar(dot) product will be the sum of the cross-products i.e. = dimension of the column. Why must we Dim and then ReDim the variables "xDim"? Is there a more efficient way to set up array computation?

```
Function OnesArray(xInput As Integer)

Dim xDim() As Variant
ReDim xDim(1 To xInput, 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To xInput Step 1
    xDim(i, 1) = 1
Next i

Dim TempArrayA() As Variant
Dim TempArrayB() As Variant

ReDim TempArrayA(LBound(xDim) To UBound(xDim))
ReDim TempArrayA(LBound(xDim) To UBound(xDim))

TempArrayA = xDim
TempArrayB = xDim

OnesArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(TempArrayA, TempArrayB)

End Function
```

The output produced is: Input 1, 2, 3. Output 1, 2, 3. Expected output

Comment: When you have code that works as intended but you would like a *more efficient* way of implementing, that's usually have a question for [codereview.se].

Comment: FWIW you don't *need* to `Dim` the two arrays if you're going to `ReDim` them right away. Code compiles and runs fine without these two `Dim` statements.

Comment: That said I'm not clear on the purpose of that code. `Debug.Print OnesArray(42)` seems like a convoluted way to do `Debug.Print 42`. It would be more interesting if you took an array for input, or even a `Range` object.

Comment: FWIW you don't even need `TempArrayA` or `TempArrayB` at all. Why not just use `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(xDim, xDim)`?

Comment: A huge waste appears to be the loop. Would it be possible to define and populate xDim in-line i.e. `xDim(1 To xInput, 1) = 1`?

It seems a lot of process code for a simple task. Is array manipulation more complex in VB compared to other languages?